# How much do poker rooms pay to use the Bravo waiting list / comp system?

Tags: casino

What are the general contract terms that casinos pay for the [Genesis Bravo system](http://www.genesisgaming.com/services)?

For context, the system provides tools for poker room management.

Comment: Poker was invented in America. Every single American poker player knows what the 'Bravo' poker app is. This question was only unclear if your never played poker.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far--it's only in a fraction of existing poker rooms, and it's only been around for a decade or so, but most active players have probably been in a room that uses it.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker I was saying that because Radu Murzea thinks the question is too vague to be understood. Gotta love SE! :) Hey Radu do you mind explaining what you find confusing about this question.. or explain how you got to be a mod on a poker forum?

Comment: I imagine like 90% of the poker players in the world, he's never heard of it. Like I said, only players who have played recently in large American casino poker rooms would have encountered it, and only some small fraction of those would have bothered to ask about it and know its name.

Comment: maybe a link to Genisis's website or an explanation of what it is would be helpful

Comment: Anyway, I asked the same question on Quora, so go search there if you want the answer. Probably good advice for any question on SE these days.

Comment: Ok chill, the question can be reopened. You yourself are taking some leaps that everyone knows what that system is, which clearly is not the case. I'd advise you to contact them yourself. I'm sure they have a dedicated sales and contracts team who would be much better to answer this than this stack exchange. You've been warned in the past for the way you comment and talk to people here, it won't be tolerated as it wasn't in the past.

Comment: I love to play poker with my friends but have never heard of this' Bravo Can I have more information about him ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer. The system cost about 12G a table. I do not know if there are recurring fees for other services.